# How can I modify input before model binding in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I intercept submitted form input and modify it before it is bound to my model? For example, if I wanted to trim the whitespace from all text.

I have tried creating a custom model binder like so:

```
public class CustomBinder : DefaultModelBinder {

  protected override void SetProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, object value) {
    string newValue = ((string)value).Trim(); //example code to create new value but could be anything
    base.SetProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor, newValue);
  }

}
```

but this doesn't seem to be invoked.  Is there a better place to modify the input value?

Note: I need to modify the value before it is bound and validated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you make sure that your model binder was used? E.g. the default model binder can be replaced by doing this in `Application_Start`:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new MyVeryOwnModelBinder();
```

I have successfully done this multiple times, applying a re-indexing operation to a POST'ed array.

I did the re-indexing by overriding the `BindModel` method, looking up posted values in the  `bindingContext.ValueProvider` dictionary.

It should be possible to just edit this dictionary in order to modify the POST'ed values before model binding.

Comment: If I override `BindModel` then I can see my CustomBinder is being invoked through the debugger but when I just override `GetProperty` it isn't.

Comment: Arghhh! I was registering my model binder against the property type using `ModelBinders.Binders.Add()` and not as the default model binder. Using `ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new CustomBinder();` invokes `SetPoperty` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Did you register the model binder in global.asax?

Comment: Yes, and if I override `BindModel` then I can see it is invoked through the debugger but not when I override `SetProperty`