# Process input before model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a Model that has an integer property. Everything works find except when a user enter a comma in the input. eg: 100,000
Is there a way to get rid of commas before model binding?

I know I can use client side javascript but perfer a server side solution

Comment: Refer [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21189158/change-default-numberstyles-on-integers) for creating a custom `ModelBinder` to accept thousands separator

Answer (score 0):

The answer could be to create a custom model binder that modifies the input. [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872883/how-can-i-modify-input-before-model-binding-in-asp-net-mvc).